# What is a Mongo cursor instance of?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor, cursor, prototype

That might seem like a stupid question, but it isn't.
In Meteor current version, Mongo.Cursor and Meteor.Collection.Cursor are the same thing. A cursor returned by collection.find is an instance of both of these constructors on client, but the same thing doesn't apply to the server.

My intention is to extend the cursors prototype, but I need the right constructor for it to work on both client and server.

Comment: Can you provide more details? `Mongo.Cursor == Meteor.Collection.Cursor` is `true` on both the client and the server.

Comment: Exactly, but Meteor.users.find() instanceof Meteor.Cursor isn't true in the server but is true in the client

Comment: Meteor uses two different implementations. This is `Cursor` on the server: https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/devel/packages/mongo/mongo_driver.js#L843. And this one on the client: https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/devel/packages/minimongo/minimongo.js#L80. Are you sure it's a good idea to extend the prototypes? :)

Comment: yeah, I actually gave up. It's probably for the best though, I'm having difficulty doing something I shouldn't do in the first place

Comment: what have u been trying to achieve in the first place?